# I can't connecty to my EC2 instances on my default VPC

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm  a new user on AWS and I'm studying with the cloud guru course for the AWS Certified Solutions Architect Associate.

While going trough the course everything worked as it was in the course, but since  a few videos I have no SSH access to my EC2 instances on the default VPC.

I just finished the VPC section of the course and I see that both instances has security groups that allows communication via 80 and 22 ports.

I also checked the network access control lists and enabled both inbound and outbound traffic for 22 and 80 ports.

The VPC has an internet Gateway and the EC2 Instances have public IP's.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't remember touching nothing more than the NACL to enable 80 and 22 ports.

### Inbound Rules

[image: Inbound Rules]

### Outbound Rules

[image: Outbound Rules]

### NACL rules

[image: NACL rules]

### Route table

[image: Route table]

Comment: Suggest you ask questions like this on the cloud guru forums. Check internet gateway, route table associated with your subnet, NACLs, SGs, and instance.

Comment: the `route table` in that VPC has the route 0.0.0.0/0 with target your internet gateway?
something like this:

`0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-0c093efc206c13dba`

Comment: @fromthestone Just added some screenshots to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Your outbound NACL is preventing return traffic to your SSH host.  The port rage is the destination port, not source.

The source port for the SSH daemon on your EC2 instance is an ephemeral port number, and the destination port is 22, just the opposite of your computer.

Remove the outbound NACL and everything will be fine.

Comment: Should I leave the outbound rule as `DENY ALL`?

Comment: If I do `ALLOW ALL TCP` the ssh connection is possible

Comment: But if I just remove all the outbound rules and leave only the `DENY ALL` or just add a rule for SSH, it stops working.

Comment: If you Deny All, then you are denying the traffic from the server to your PC.  So nothing works.

Comment: But if I try to allow only Port 22, I also don't have access.

Comment: The port number in the ACL is the destination port. That is a high number port. The source port is 22.

Comment: Then, should I use a ephemeral ports for outbound on the NACL?

Comment: You *can*, however I'm not clear what your goal is.  What are you trying to prevent your server from doing?

Comment: I want to have only the minimal required ports open for both, inbound and outbound traffic.

Comment: Well then, go ahead and allow ephemeral ports.  I'm not sure you're doing anything useful, but it won't hurt.

Comment: My only concern is because once on a previous job some of our servers were hacked to attack another servers inside AWS. I personally think that's the best approach always.